# Please include additional links to other communities on the Careers site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Would be nice to have separates links (or fixed buttons) to other sites like xing.com or linkedin.com in the CV.

So additional or similar information could be shared.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can already do that in the Projects and Links box. From the help:

"Are there any public or open source projects you've participated in that you'd like to share? Perhaps something on SourceForge, CodePlex, Github, Google Code, or similar?
Is there anything else on the internet that shows off who you are and what you do – screencasts, blog entries, slideshows, presentations, videos, whatever? Link to it here, and briefly describe why it's awesome.
This field supports plain text with linebreaks, and automatic hyperlinking in the form...
http://www.example.com/
... so don't be shy about linking to anything cool and interesting you'd like to share!"

Answer (score 0):

Now that all the free text fields support full Markdown, you should be able to link to your heart's content!